# onChange running 2 pieces of script Joined on 1 spreadsheet - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I thought I coded this correctly but it isnt working. Could someone please assist. Thanks In Advance

```
  function onChange(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
 .getName() !== "ONLINE RELOCATION" || e.range.columnStart !== 7 || e.range.rowStart === 3) return;
  e.range.offset(0, -3)
 .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null)

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  if(col === 7 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "ONLINE RELOCATION"){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,5).setValue('RELOCATIONINONLINE');
  }
  }
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any errors? What's your expected result? We need more information to be able to find the issue.

Comment: When I add data to Column G (i.e row 4) I expect to see todays date in Column D & RELOCATIONINONLINE in ColumnE in row 4. I am not seeing anything in column D or E. Not sure what I have missed in the code. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Can you please share a copy of the sheet and the full code if you have more? Remember to not share personal info and ID.

Comment: Have you installed(set up) the trigger?